# Set right type for objectAtIndex through data model

Tags: ios

From didSelectRowAtIndexPath I would like to set a ID value in my data model and use it to create a dictionnary.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        NSDictionary *item = [self.dataSource objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        NSNumber *productCat =[item objectForKey:@"UUID"];
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"Details" sender:productCat];
    }


-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
        if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"Details"]){
            DataModel* media = [DataModel getInstance];
            media.productID = sender;
        }
}
```

DataModel.h :

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) NSNumber  *productID;
-(void)productDetails;
```

DataModel.m :

```
-(void)productDetails {
    NSDictionary* details = [_products objectAtIndex:_productID];
...
}
```

I get this warning on the dictionnary: "Incompatible pointer to pointer conversion sending NSNumber to parameter of type NSUInteger".

If I change productID type to NSUinteger then media.productID = sender throws an implicit conversion error. Everything I try ends up in a warning or an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace

```
[_products objectAtIndex:_productID];
```

with

```
[_products objectAtIndex:[_productID integerValue]];
```

reason is _productID is an object type (NSNumber) and objectAtIndex take integer value.

Comment: @Zaph because _productID is an object type (NSNumber) and objectAtIndex take integer value.

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass an unsigned integer value, not NSNumber, as the warning said you.

```
NSDictionary* details = [_products objectAtIndex:[_productID unsignedIntegerValue]];
```